# C# - Custom constructor in a child class

Tags: c#, constructor

I've a base class:

```
class SDKBaseClass
{
    public SDKBaseClass();
    public SDKBaseClass(EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
}
```

To create an object of a SDKBaseClass:

```
string host = "192.168.0.1";
string port = "4321";

Uri uri = new Uri(string.Concat(new String[] {
    "net.tcp://", host, ":", port
}));

SDKBaseClass sdkBaseClass = new SDKBaseClass(new EndpointAddress(uri, new AddressHeader[0]));
```

I would like to create child class which inherits from SDKBaseClass:

```
class SDKChildClass : SDKBaseClass
{
    SDKChildClass(string host, string port);
}
```

and where Uri object is created inside SDKChildClass constructor:

```
public SDKChildClass(string host, string port)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Concat(new String[] {
        "net.tcp://", host, ":", port
    }));

    //what's next?
}
```

I'm lost and I don't what should be next in SDKChildClass constructor. Should it inherits from one of the constructors of a base class?

PS. SDKBaseClass comes from DLL library so I have no knowledge about its constructors implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Move the URI construction logic to a method and call it like this:

```
public SDKChildClass(string host, string port) : base(ConstructEndpoint(host, port))
{
}
```

This is known as constructor chaining.  You can chain to base() and this()

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're looking for something like that:

```
class SDKChildClass : SDKBaseClass
{
    SDKChildClass(string host, string port)
      :base(new Uri(host, port)) // base class constructor call
    {
    }
}
```

In case you have an *elaborated logic*, put it into appropraite `private static` method

```
class SDKChildClass : SDKBaseClass 
{
   private static Uri createUri(host, port) 
   {
      //TODO: put all the logic here
   }

   SDKChildClass(string host, string port)
     :base(createUri(host, port)) // base class constructor call
   {
   }
 }
```

Comment: AKA constructor chaining

Answer (score 2):

```
class SDKChildClass : SDKBaseClass
{
    public SDKChildClass(string host, string port)
        : base(new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://" + host + ":" + port)))
}
```